# Insertion sort in Racket, cannot figure out why this doesn't work

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, insertion-sort

I am new to Racket, and I am trying to figure out insertion sort. This is what I have but I am getting an error, and I can not figure it out from debugging.

```
;Definition of insert: inserts a number into an already sorted list based on
;the cmp parameter
;cmp: < or >, L1: a list, n: the number to be inserted
(define (insert cmp L1 n)
  (cond
    ((null? n) (list L1))
    ((null? L1) (cons n L1))
    ((cmp n (car L1)) (cons n L1))
    (else (cons (car L1) (insert cmp (cdr L1) n)))
   )
)

;Definition of insertionSort: sorts a list based on a recursive insertion sort
;L1: a list, cmp: < or >
(define (insertionSort L1 cmp)
  (cond
    ((null? L1) L1)
    (else (insert cmp (car L1) (insertionSort(cdr L1) cmp)))
  )
)
```

Comment: The `(null? n)` case in `insert` isn't very useful since `n` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Following functions work:

```
(define (insert n l cmp (ol '()))
  (cond
    [(empty? l)
     (append ol (list n))] ; or: (reverse (cons n (reverse ol)))
    [(not (cmp n (first l)))
     (append ol (list n) l)]
    [else (insert n
                  (rest l)
                  cmp
                  (append ol (list (first l))) ; or:  (reverse (cons (first l) (reverse ol)))
                  )] ))

(define (isort l cmp (sl '()))
  (cond
    [(empty? l) sl]
    [else (isort (rest l)
                 cmp
                 (insert (first l)
                         sl
                         cmp))] ))
```

These functions appear to be tail-recursive.

Testing:

```
(isort '(4 2 5 8 1 4 7 3 6 9) >)
(isort '(4 2 5 8 1 4 7 3 6 9) <)
```

Output:

```
'(1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9)
'(9 8 7 6 5 4 4 3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "flipped" the arguments for `insert` when you use it in `insertionSort`; it should be

```
(define (insertionSort L1 cmp)
  (cond
    ((null? L1) L1)
    (else (insert cmp (insertionSort (cdr L1) cmp) (car L1)))))
```